# Jetty 9 Error: Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HttpInput failure

Tags: jetty-9

I am using the Jetty 9.4.15 server to deploy the war in a standalone mode with the Http2.

The number of concurrent streams configured are jetty.http2.maxConcurrentStreams=1000 instead of default 128. This is because I am getting too many concurrent streams error as the client is having more streams.

The application is working fine, except some sporadic errors as shown below in the server logs.

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Reset cancel_stream_error
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory$HTTPServerSessionListener.onReset(HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory.java:156) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.notifyReset(HTTP2Stream.java:574) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.onReset(HTTP2Stream.java:343) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.process(HTTP2Stream.java:252) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session.onReset(HTTP2Session.java:294) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser$Listener$Wrapper.onReset(Parser.java:368) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.BodyParser.notifyReset(BodyParser.java:139) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.ResetBodyParser.onReset(ResetBodyParser.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.ResetBodyParser.parse(ResetBodyParser.java:66) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:194) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:123) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.ServerParser.parse(ServerParser.java:115) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$HTTP2Producer.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:248) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:357) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:181) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HttpInput failure
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.failed(HttpInput.java:831) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HttpChannelOverHTTP2.onFailure(HttpChannelOverHTTP2.java:323) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HTTP2ServerConnection.onStreamFailure(HTTP2ServerConnection.java:219) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.server.HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory$HTTPServerSessionListener.onReset(HTTP2ServerConnectionFactory.java:156) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.notifyReset(HTTP2Stream.java:574) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.onReset(HTTP2Stream.java:343) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Stream.process(HTTP2Stream.java:252) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session.onReset(HTTP2Session.java:294) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser$Listener$Wrapper.onReset(Parser.java:368) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.BodyParser.notifyReset(BodyParser.java:139) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.ResetBodyParser.onReset(ResetBodyParser.java:97) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.ResetBodyParser.parse(ResetBodyParser.java:66) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:194) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:123) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.parser.ServerParser.parse(ServerParser.java:115) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$HTTP2Producer.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:248) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produceTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:357) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:181) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

`

The client logs shows the below error.

`Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers.`

The client is using streaming instead of waiting for complete response. I am not sure why this error is occurring some times. The client timeout is configured as 30 Seconds, I checked the application logs, where the application processing logic never exceeded 2 seconds.

Could someone help me in finding the root cause for this issue?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3670

Comment: It signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during the input.